# Using BitMap object without locking the resource

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, unmanagedresources

From an answer in a previous question, given by `Hans Passant` I understood that :

```
 MyImage = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
 pictureBox1.Image = (Image)MyImage;
```

> Yes, that code puts a lock on the file. The lock is produced by a
>   memory mapped file object that GDI+ creates to efficiently map the
>   pixel data of the file into memory without having to allocate space in
>   the paging file. You will not be able to delete the file as long as
>   the image is displayed in the picture box and not disposed, the lock
>   prevents that.

The question was about an error(sometimes) when I tried to delete a previously used image from the `PictureBox`. It seems that in this exact situation even calling:

```
if (MyImage != null)
{
    MyImage.Dispose();
}
```

doesn't guarantee that when the time comes to delete the image(i guess this could be any kind of unmanaged resource) it will be disposed.

So I have two questions - the first is related to my current problem with using `BitMap` in the `PictureBox` and the locking of the resource caused by that. I saw that this is not the only way to show an image inside the `PictureBox` so is there another way which won't cause this problem and will guarantee that the image is released to be deleted anytime I need to.

And my second question - what is the basic approach when I have to work with unmanaged resources in .NET and I need to do operations like `Delete` with them. I guess this problem may come up when working with any kind of unmanaged resource in .NET, is there a common approach to solve the problem with the locking/releasing the resource in a certain moment and not relaying on the `Garbage Collector` (which obviously will fail you from time to time since it may take different time for releasing). I saw that some use `GC...` methods to call explicitly `finilizer` and stuff like that but a college mention that it's better to not use those methods since they may cause unpredictable problems.

So any guidelines, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "common approach" to what you describe is `IDisposable` and the `Dispose()` method, most commonly exposed via `using`. If that isn't working in a specific example, then there may be a coding bug in that specific example. That bug doesn't change the common approach.

Re that one example; try loading it in memory instead:

```
var data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
var ms = new MemoryStream(data);
MyImage = Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
```